# Get document libraries for domain-my.sharepoint.com

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to access the document libraries created by a user in their own `domain-my.sharepoint.com`, based on the documentation I inferred that the way to do it is

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/domain-my.sharepoint.com/drives
```

As drives map to document library(?)

I'm able to make this work with `domain.sharepoint.com`, but unable to make it work with `domain-my.sharepoint.com`

here is what it says:

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": "invalidRequest",
        "message": "Provided id is not suitable for the current host",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "09c5722c-cfc3-4589-ba76-e57c44590d16",
            "date": "2017-06-27T06:53:59"
        }
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? We're hitting the same issue

Comment: using sharepoint API is the way to go!

Comment: Thanks for responding, but I'm not sure what you mean... As you've said in your question, using the Sharepoint API, we can't see those `domain-my....` domains.

Comment: It looks like there is now an attempt to support this behavior: https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/issues/791

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is the [OneDrive endpoint](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/onedrive). You can access the current user's `drive` using `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive`/

Comment: hi marc the scenario is that user has created a new document library under his domain-my.sharepoint.com, I am not able to figure out a way to get to that. /me/drive gives me a drive mapped to domain-my.sharepoint.com.

Comment: Actually having the `/sites` endpoint support the OneDrive for Business hostname would make certain use-cases way easier. Because the OneDrive endpoints don't support the SharePoint IDs. So it's really painful to use those parts of the Graph API when all other O365 APIs returns IDs in UUIDv4 format but the Graph API is mostly using a different format. And after all ODB is still just SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get what you want is via a request to:

`https://domain-my.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0/sites/domain-my.sharepoint.com/drives`

Basically the `/_api/v2.0/sites` endpoints seems to support everything that is documented in the corresponding Graph API docs.

Comment: `/_api/v2.0/sites` is the SharePoint REST API, not Microsoft Graph. They are distinct APIs and the scopes and tokens required to access it may be different.

Comment: Are they really that distinct? It looks and feels a lot like the Graph API. Of course it only allows access to SharePoint resources and not the whole slew of O365 services.

But this is at least a workaround as long as he has access to it. I had to use it actually to workaround deficiencies in the Graph API.

Comment: @smotti the question was around OneDrive graph API, if you see the comments in the question we ended up using sharepoint API. So the simple answer is not "another way", the answer is no it doesn't work. I think that's why folks have downvoted your answer.